# Accessing Keyword and category in Event code 2011

Tags: 2011, event-system

I want some help accessing the categories and keywords from event code. The below code worked in Tridion 2009 event code, but i am unable to get some classes in new event code.

```
Keyword keyword = null;
Keywords parentKeywords = null; //not available in Tridion 2011
TDSEClass class2 = null;
Category category = null;

EventHelper.WriteEventToHTMLLog("Getting all the Case study keywords that tagged the component");

//ListColumnFilter is an enum with the Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDSDefines
//(compCurrent.GetListKeywords is not available in Tridion 2011
XDocument document =     XDocument.Parse(compCurrent.GetListKeywords(ListColumnFilter.XMLListExtended).Replace("tcm:Item", "tcmItem"));

foreach (XElement element in document.Descendants("tcmItem"))
{
    string uRI = (element.Attribute("ID") != null) ? element.Attribute("ID").Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
    string str9 = (element.Attribute("OrgItemID") != null) ? element.Attribute("OrgItemID").Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
    category = (Category)class2.GetObject(str9, EnumOpenMode.OpenModeView,    class2.GetPublication(compCurrent.Publication.ID), XMLReadFilter.XMLReadAll);
    EventHelper.WriteEventToHTMLLog("Found Category with name: " + category.Title);
    keyword = (Keyword)class2.GetObject(uRI, EnumOpenMode.OpenModeView,     class2.GetPublication(compCurrent.Publication.ID), XMLReadFilter.XMLReadAll);

    parentKeywords = keyword.ParentKeywords;
    EventHelper.WriteEventToHTMLLog("keyword parent found");
    if (parentKeywords != null)
    {
        foreach (Keyword keyword2 in parentKeywords)
        {
            EventHelper.WriteEventToHTMLLog("kword.Title" + keyword2.Title);
            title = keyword2.Title;
        }
    }
}
```

Keywords class is unavailable in new event code. Please help.

Comment: I have to admit I have problems reading through this code... could you explain what you're trying to do instead of only posting the code? And yes, of course there is a Keyword class in 2011+.

Comment: In addition to what Nuno has said, it would be great if you state what exactly you want to access or do

Comment: @Nuno, I was trying to acess the keyword which are taggged to the component. I wanted to access the keyword title..

Answer (score 3):

Like Nuno mentioned, I am not quite sure what your code is supposed to do. However, keywords can be accessed in 2011 via the following:

```
// TcmUri (itemId, itemType, pubId)
TcmUri categoryTcmUri = new TcmUri(5021, ItemType.Category, 45);
var category = component.Session.GetObject(categoryTcmUri) as Category;
var kws = category.GetKeywords();
foreach(Keyword kw in kws)
{
     // do something with the keyword
}
```

While my answer is quite general, I am not entirely sure what you are looking to do with the keywords. If you could clarify I am sure someone would be glad to help you out if this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: ,, thanks i was looking to access keyword, i will try this and get back if any issues.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how I would read all Keywords linked to a component (taking into account multi-value `Keyword` fields, and `EmbeddedSchema` fields.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Tridion.ContentManager;
using Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement;
using Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Fields;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.Events;

namespace ReadKeywordsFromComponents
{
    [TcmExtension("Do Something")]
    public class DoSomething : TcmExtension, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly List<EventSubscription> _subscriptions = 
            new List<EventSubscription>();

        public DoSomething()
        {
            SubscribeEvents();
        }

        private void SubscribeEvents()
        {
            EventSubscription subscription = EventSystem.Subscribe<Component, 
                SaveEventArgs>(DoSomethingOnSave, EventPhases.Initiated);
            _subscriptions.Add(subscription);
        }

        private void DoSomethingOnSave(Component component, 
                                       SaveEventArgs args, 
                                       EventPhases phases)
        {
            Dictionary<TcmUri, Keyword> keywords = new Dictionary<Keyword>();
            if (component.ComponentType == ComponentType.Normal)
            {
                ItemFields content = new ItemFields(component.Content, component.Schema);
                GetKeywordsFromFields(content, keywords);
            }
        }


        private static void GetKeywordsFromFields(IEnumerable<ItemField> content,
                                                  Dictionary<TcmUri, Keyword> keywords)
        {
            foreach (ItemField field in content)
            {
                if (field is KeywordField)
                {
                    KeywordField keyField = (KeywordField) field;
                    foreach (Keyword keyword in keyField.Values)
                    {
                        if (!keywords.ContainsKey(keyword.Id))
                        {
                            keywords.Add(keyword.Id, keyword);
                            // If you only need the title, you could do it like this.
                            string title = keyword.Title;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (field is EmbeddedSchemaField)
                {
                    EmbeddedSchemaField embeddedSchema = (EmbeddedSchemaField) field;
                    foreach (ItemFields fields in embeddedSchema.Values)
                    {
                        GetKeywordsFromFields(fields, keywords);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            foreach (EventSubscription subscription in _subscriptions)
            {
                subscription.Unsubscribe();
            }
        }
    }
}
```